# There is nothing happening when store data for Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel

I making laravel API where i can store a new data where the value in body raw json. but when i try to send request using post, i got nothing but the status is 200 OK. when i chek my mysql there is no data inputed.
So, what should i do?

**mysql data**

[image]

**Laravel Controller, and API,**

```
// function in controller
use App\Models\ChartAge;
class ChartController extends Controller
{
   public function saveChart(Request $request)
   {
    $data = $request->validate([
        'entity' => 'required|string|max:10',
        'code' => 'required|string|max:10',
        'year' => 'required|int|max:10',
        'under_age_15' => 'required|string|max:50',
        'age_15_64' => 'required|string|max:50',
        'age_65_over' => 'required|string|max:50',
    ]);

    $values = ChartAge::create($request);

    return response()->json(
        [
            'status' => true,
            'message' => "the videos has been favorites",
            'data' => $values,
        ],
        201
    );
   }
}
//in api.php
Route::post("charts", [ChartController::class, 'saveChart']);
```

and here is when i tried to send request using postman.

[image]

because there is no error, i don't know what's wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First double check your ChartAge model, does it have $fillable or not?

and Edit your code:

From

```
$values = ChartAge::create($request);
```

To:

```
$values = ChartAge::create($request->all());
```

Hope this will be useful.

With validation:

```
$data = \Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'entity' => 'required|string|max:10',
    'code' => 'required|string|max:10',
    'year' => 'required|int|max:10',
    'under_age_15' => 'required|string|max:50',
    'age_15_64' => 'required|string|max:50',
    'age_65_over' => 'required|string|max:50',
]);

if($data-> fails()){
  return back()->withErrors($data)->withInput();
}

$values = ChartAge::create($request->all());
```

Comment: it work that way, but, the validations will be skipped, is there a way that i can use validate too?

Answer (score 0):

Do you set fillable fields in your 'ChartAge' model?
protected $fillable = ['entity','code','year'...];
Do you try to test code with disabling validation?
Please try to put dd($request) in the first row of the controller code.

Method create expects a plain PHP array, not a Request object.

Comment: yes i was, i've already do it that many of time, should i edited my post and put my chartage model? and yes i test the code when disabling the validations using request dumping the data request the value are showing up. but when i comment the dumping, its response 200 ok. still got no clue what's happen there

Comment: I think you should test function ChartAge::create()  by passing just plain PHP array with only values that this function expected. $data = [
        'entity' => 'test value',
        'code' => 'test',
        'year' => 'test',
        'under_age_15' => 'test',
        'age_15_64' => 'test',
        'age_65_over' => 'test',
    ]);    ChartAge::create($data)  Because in you code ChartAge::create($request) instead of ChartAge::create($data)